# Remove Malware from files? (Except Anti-Virus)

Tags: virus

How to remove malware from files?

Files may be images, documents or videos.

Except Anti-Virus are there any other ways available?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you asking about removing malware from files (i.e. you have an infected file and want to repair it without having a backup), or are you asking about removing malware from your laptop in general (your laptop is infected and you want to clean it)?

Comment: Am asking about removing malware from files (i.e. you have an infected file and want to repair it,but i don't have anti-virus software,so is there anyother way to remove malware?

Comment: Full format of drive and reinstall the system.

Comment: @Overmind If i do that,I will lost my files,Correct.?

Comment: Depends on file types/how you store them.

Comment: You cannot. You need to restore files from backup.

Comment: Isn't that kind of the definition of a what an anti-virus does? I.e. if something removes malware content from files, wouldn't it invariably be antivirus software?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you create fresh copies of the files, transcribing only the parts that you can verify clean using methods that you can verify secure.  This may be risky.

For example, if you have a document that might be infected, you might re-type it on another computer.  Obviously, don't type parts of the document that might be virus-related, e.g. a macro you can't 100% prove to be non-malicious.  Then the new copy would, ideally, be safe.

Theoretically, if someone's got a lot of documents, they might try to automate the process:

1. Create a server that constructs new documents on a clean computer.
2. Create a client that dictates from the infected documents on the old computer.
3. Obviously, don't have the server simply copy *everything* – instead, have it recreate only content that's definitely safe; everything else will be lost (unless you want to take some calculated risks).
4. Allow the client to connect to the server over a secure format that you're willing to bet the infection can't side-channel through.

   - For example, if you copy it by hand, then you're betting the virus can't hack your brain.
   - For example, if you copy it by a network socket, then you're betting that the virus can't hack the server through whatever network protocol is involved.

I'd speculate that someone's probably set up a service centered around this where:

1. They operate a server with appropriate security measures.
2. Users can download a client onto their infected machine.
3. The client dictates the files to the server, which allows reproduction of verified-clean material.
4. Users can download the verified-clean documents from the server onto a new device.

That said, I can't recommend a service that does this.. just seems like there should already be one, or else it could be a potentially great side-project for someone.  Obviously, you'd need to be able to trust the service provider.

Finally, to be clear, trying to recover infected content can be dangerous.

Comment: Does anyone know a service like this?  I vaguely recall writing my own scripts to do stuff like this before, but seems like someone would've made a business out of it by now.  For example, having a VSTO add-in for a client could help reconstruct Microsoft Office documents, which'd seem like something enterprise-class clients would be a fan of.